Failed to import transformers.pipelines because of the following error: generic_type: type "InterpreterWrapper" is already registered
I get the following error when I import the pipeline module from transformers:
from transformers import pipeline
sentiment_analysis = pipeline("sentiment-analysis", model="siebert/sentiment-roberta-large-english")
print(sentiment_analysis("I love this!"))

Error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\transformers\utils\import_utils.py:1535, in _LazyModule._get_module(self, module_name)
   1534 try:
-> 1535     return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.__name__)
   1536 except Exception as e:

File c:\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py:90, in import_module(name, package)
     89         level += 1
---> 90 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1387, in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1360, in _find_and_load(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:935, in _load_unlocked(spec)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:995, in exec_module(self, module)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:488, in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\transformers\pipelines\__init__.py:26
     25 from ..feature_extraction_utils import PreTrainedFeatureExtractor
...
   1539         f" traceback):\n{e}"
   1540     ) from e

RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.pipelines because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
generic_type: type "InterpreterWrapper" is already registered!

The transformers library installs just fine:
import transformers

How can I solve this?
